# How to select item at cursor position in wheel layout

Tags: android

```
  <github.hellocsl.cursorwheel.CursorWheelLayout
        android:id="@+id/wheel_image"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:wheelBackgroundColor="#ffff"
        app:wheelItemRotateMode="none"
        app:wheelSelectedAngle="270">

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/id_wheel_menu_center_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


    </github.hellocsl.cursorwheel.CursorWheelLayout>
```

Java code:

```
 wheel_image = (CursorWheelLayout) findViewById(R.id.wheel_image);



    loadData();

    wheel_image.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    wheel_image.setOnMenuSelectedListener(this);


private void loadData() {

    lstImage = new ArrayList<>();

    lstImage.add(new ImageData(R.drawable.court, "Assign Authority"));
    lstImage.add(new ImageData(R.drawable.speaker_icon, "Next Date of Hearing"));
    lstImage.add(new ImageData(R.drawable.add_person, "Register Client"));
    lstImage.add(new ImageData(R.drawable.register_saff, "Register Staff"));
    lstImage.add(new ImageData(R.drawable.finish_case, "Case Finish"));
    lstImage.add(new ImageData(R.drawable.chatting, "Messaging"));

    WheelImageAdapter imgAdapter = new WheelImageAdapter(getBaseContext(), lstImage);
    wheel_image.setAdapter(imgAdapter);
}

public void onItemSelected(CursorWheelLayout parent, View view, int pos) {


    if (parent.getId() == R.id.wheel_image) {

        TextView textView;
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selct_view);
        textView.setText(lstImage.get(pos).imageDescription);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int pos) {
    Intent intent = null;

    if (pos == 0) {

        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, Assign_authority.class);

    } else if (pos == 1) {


        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, ClientCases.class);
        intent.putExtra("key","assign next date");


    } else if (pos == 2) {


        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, UpdateClient.class);


    } else if (pos == 3) {


        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, UpdateStaff.class);


    } else if (pos == 4) {


        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, Case_finish.class);


    } else if (pos == 5) {


        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, ClientCases.class);
        intent.putExtra("key","message");

    }

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Its running perfectly. but when i click on cursor position of wheel layout, item is not clicked. i did not know what is the problem in code. or some line of code is missing. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

in CursorWheelLayout.java there is condition for ignore the origin onClickListener. so if you want to perform click at origin or cursor position then add library as module & comment below lines in InnerClickListener.

```
if (mSelectedView == v || mTempSelectedView == v) {
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **CursorWheelLayout** library, you can almost all your work within the **onItemSelected** method and do not need to use the onItemClick method.
You can use this form :

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(CursorWheelLayout parent, View view, int pos) {

    Intent intent = null;

    if (pos == 0) {
    intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, Assign_authority.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (pos == 1) {
        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, Assign_authority.class);
        intent.putExtra("key","assign next date");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (pos == 2) {
        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, UpdateClient.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (pos == 3) {
        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, UpdateStaff.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (pos == 4) {
        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, Case_finish.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (pos == 5) {
        intent = new Intent(WheelView.this, ClientCases.class);
        intent.putExtra("key","message");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```